# Jquery on.load is not working in chrome extension even with local jquery copy

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension and I have the following files. 
But the h1-title is not getting updated when I open https://example.com/ 
I don't see any error in dev consoles. What am I missing here?

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Print Hello",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "48": "images/icon-48.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "48": "images/icon-48.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Print Hello"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://example.com/"],
            "js": ["./scripts/jquery.min.js", "./scripts/print_hello.js"]
        }
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://example.com/"
    ]
}
```

print_hello.js

```
function print_hello() {
    document.querySelector("div h1").innerText = "Hello!"
}

$(document).on("load", print_hello)
```

Comment: Replace `https://example.com/` with `*://*.example.com/*`

Answer (score -1):

Can you try modifying your code with the document ready?

So the `print_hello.js` will be

```
function print_hello() {
    document.querySelector("div h1").innerText = "Hello!"
}

$(document ).ready( print_hello);

// or

// $( window ).on( "load", print_hello );
// instead of document `window` for accessing the the document ready.
```

Comment: The `ready` event executes _before_ the `load` event so I don't think this would be the solution

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean this is not a solution?

We only need the document structure, and so the elements will be available on ready state. We are not caring about the asynchronous files. So, I think the above one would be a right solution.

Comment: If OP's code doesn't work, running the same thing for an _earlier_ event won't fix anything. As per the duplicate, both OP's code and this answer run too late to attach their respective event listeners; the `load` and `ready` events have already fired

Comment: Its not an earlier event. Its known thing that document.load is not exist in jQuery. `window.load` or `document.ready`  is the right way of firing the `ready` events. May be you are confused what I am suggesting or missing the details.

Lets wait for the author input.